# $lookup on Embedded Documents in MongoDB: Does order of values matter?

Tags: mongodb

I have two similar collections within the same database which I am trying to merge using $lookup and the aggregate pipeline.  Their _ids, which I'm using as the matching field, contain the same values, but in a different order:

Collection1:

```
{ "_id" : { "State" : "Vermont", "Race" : "Black American or African American" }, "Population" : 6456 }
```

Collection2:

```
{ "_id" : { "Race" : "Multiracial", "State" : "Arkansas" }, "Population" : 48996 }
```

I tried running the aggregate pipeline as follows:

```
db.Collection1.aggregate([{$lookup: {from: "Collection2", localField: "_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "Population"}}])
```

However, when I do that, I get:

```
{ "_id" : { "Race" : "Multiracial", "State" : "Arkansas" }, "Population" : [ ] }
```

I'd like to get the values for population within the array.  I'm fairly new to MongoDB.  Is there something wrong with my syntax for the aggregate command, or is it failing because 'Race' and 'State' are listed in a different order within the embedded document _id?  Does the order of the values matter for matching on embedded documents?

Thank you so much for your time, and I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Generally, when matching embedded documents the field order does indeed matter; see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/340269/89577 for a good discussion of this.